# Packaged & Installed UWP App Not In Start Menu

Tags: windows, powershell, uwp

I generated the app package for my UWP project via sideload and installed it with the Powershell script that was made. Although the app installed and a folder was made in WindowsApps I cannot launch the app because it is not in the Start Menu. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit:

Applications tag in WAP Package Manifest:

```
<Applications>
 <Application Id="App"
    Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
    EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
  <uap:VisualElements
    DisplayName="WorksPackage2"
    Description="Package"
    BackgroundColor="transparent"
    Square150x150Logo="Images\Square150x150Logo.png"
    Square44x44Logo="Images\Square44x44Logo.png"
    AppListEntry="none">
    <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Images\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
    <uap:SplashScreen Image="Images\SplashScreen.png" />
  </uap:VisualElements>
    <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService">
            <uap:AppService Name="iTunesConnection" />
        </uap:Extension>
        <desktop:Extension
          xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"
          Category="windows.fullTrustProcess"
          Executable="iTunesConsole\iTunesConsole.exe">
        </desktop:Extension>
    </Extensions>
</Application>
```

Applications tag in UWP Manifest:

```
<Applications>
<Application Id="App"
  Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
  EntryPoint="Works.App">
  <uap:VisualElements
    DisplayName="Works"
    Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
    Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
    Description="Works"
    BackgroundColor="transparent">
    <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png"/>
    <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
  </uap:VisualElements>
    <Extensions>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.appExtension">
            <uap3:AppExtension Name="microsoft.gameBarUIExtension"
                               Id="YourUniqueIdHere"
                               DisplayName="iTunes Controller"
                               Description="desc"
                               PublicFolder="GameBar">
                <uap3:Properties>
                    <GameBarWidget Type="Standard">
                        <HomeMenuVisible>true</HomeMenuVisible>
                        <PinningSupported>true</PinningSupported>
                        <Window>
                            <Size>
                                <Height>300</Height>
                                <Width>400</Width>
                                <MinHeight>150</MinHeight>
                                <MinWidth>200</MinWidth>
                                <MaxHeight>1000</MaxHeight>
                                <MaxWidth>1000</MaxWidth>
                            </Size>
                            <ResizeSupported>
                                <Horizontal>true</Horizontal>
                                <Vertical>true</Vertical>
                            </ResizeSupported>
                        </Window>
                    </GameBarWidget>
                </uap3:Properties>
            </uap3:AppExtension>
        </uap3:Extension>
    </Extensions>
</Application>
```

Comment: Can you post the snippet of AppXManifest.xml that declares your app?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have:

```
AppListEntry="none"
```

which says "please don't add an entry to the Start menu."

Comment: Thank you this fixed my issue